# Django convert all dates in a recordset to timezone aware

Tags: python, django, django-timezone

I have a django model that uses mysql as a db, and I am using timezone support. I have a field in my model that has a date.

Since mysql cannot store timezone info inside the datefield, I store the timezone offset in a another field. When I query the database, I want to convert all the dates to timezone aware, using the offset that is stored in the database.

You can assume that my model looks like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="publish date")
    pubDate_tz = models.IntegerField()
```

and my query currently is:

```
items = Item.objects.all().filter(channel__category = category, pubDate__range=[today_date, tomorrow_date]).order_by('-pubDate')
```

But in my template I want the use of item.pubDate to automatically convert to my local timezone.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `pubDate` naive UTC datetime?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. How can I "bulk" convert it to datetime aware?

Answer (score 0):

try using timezone.make_aware in your query?

info in the docs here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

a basic example for timezone_aware conversion:

```
today = timezone.now()

today_aware = timezone.make_aware(time_ago, timezone.get_default_timezone())
```

so youd replace timezone.now with your item.pudbate query

if the timezone is always the same , you can set the timezone using the 2nd argument (timezone.get_default_timezone) , if the timezone changes you should be able to set it as the value from the database

Comment: This won't work for me, I need to convert all the timezones, not just one.